# Using grafana counter to visualize weather data

Tags: go, prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to visualize my weather data using grafana. I've already made the prometheus part and now I face an issue that hunts me for quite a while.

I created an counter that adds temperature indoor every five minutes.

```
var tempIn = prometheus.NewCounter(prometheus.CounterOpts{
    Name: "tempin",
    Help: "Temperature indoor",
})

for {
   tempIn.Add(station.Body.Devices[0].DashboardData.Temperature)
   time.Sleep(time.Second*300)
}
```

How can I now visualize this data that it shows current temperature and stores it for unlimited time so I can look at it even 1 year later like an normal graph?

`tempin{instance="localhost:9999"}` will only display added up temperature so its useless for me. I need the current temperature not the added up one. I also tried `rate(tempin{instance="localhost:9999"}[5m])`

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I encourage you to consider using a [Gauge](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge) rather than a [Counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) for this metric. Gauges are a good type for measurements that increase and decrease. Counters are best used for "counting" things. For example, you could use a Counter to count the number of times that you've measured the temperature.

Comment: Using a Gauge should make it straightforward to graph temperatures (and apply statistical calculations min, max, p95 etc.) over time.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I also measure rain and wind data and graphs would be very great there.

Comment: Prometheus persists metrics data using an in-built time-series databases that uses local storage. If you need it, there are remote storage options too. Please the documentation for [storage](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/)

Comment: I also face the same problem while trying to visualize requests per seconds on my webserver so I really need an solution for this with graphs.

Comment: To produce graphs, you'll want to define the underlying metrics correctly. Graphs show metric data over time. If you were to convert `tempIn` to a Gauge as I propose, then you could graph the temperature over time as `tempIn{}`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a counter is not the best solution for this use case, you can use the operator increase.

`Increase(tempin{instance="localhost:9999"}[5m])`

This will tell you how much the counter increased in the last five minutes